# How to determine SharePoint version used during backup creation in order to restore it?

Tags: powershell, backup, restore

I have a SC backup, but when trying to restore it on my test environment with PowerShell, got the following error: SharePoint server version mismatch. SharePoint versions on both servers should match.  [In my case version should be 4190 to continue restore].

It is possible to determine Sharepoint version used during backup creation?

Restoring with PowerShell (Restore-SPSite cmdlet)

Thanks.

Comment: If you can access the farm where the backup came from, you can look up the version. If not, I don't believe there is a (documented) way to extract the version from the site collection backup file itself

Answer (score 1):

To check which SharePoint-related installed apps are in your server - use the following PowerShell code to list out the apps & their versions:

```
$fooApps = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Product  | where {$_.Name -like "*SharePoint*"} 
$fooApps | Sort -Property Name | ft -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Todd Klindt's script](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=357) as a basis (use minor instead of major version?)